# How many syllables do these rules say that ‘every’ has?

Tags: writing, phonology, phonetics, syllables

<sup>**Edit note**: As you’ll see from the linked-to post, I’m not expecting my code here to be anything like 100% accurate. I’m after a fast and dirty heuristic that will be correct most of the time.</sup>

---

I’m using some formulaic rules for determining the number of
syllables in an English word, then comparing those rules’
result against the result produced by some code I wrote. I’m using
the “Written Method” rules that are described under [Syllable
Rules](https://medium.com/@mholtzscher/programmatically-counting-syllables-ca760435fab4#:%7E:text=Counting%20Syllables%20By%20Hand&text=Put%20your%20hand%20under%20your,is%20the%20number%20of%20syllables.) at the linked website.  However, I’m sure the syllable rules for English
are the same everywhere.

I’ve translated these rules to code and begun testing using my
code and then checking with an online syllable counter to see if
it returns the same result.  For that I’m using this free
online tool, [Syllable Counter](https://syllablecounter.net/count).

However, when it comes to the word *every*, I can’t seem to
figure out why the online service is returning two syllables
because when I use the rules, it’s clearly three syllables—at
least to me at this point, but maybe I’m missing something.

Looking at the rules, *every* has two vowel-letters and also ends
with the letter ‹y›, which sounds like a vowel, giving us a
grand total of three syllables. There is no diphthong or
triphthong in the word, nor any silent ‹e›, either.

So using those “written rules” in English, how would one come
up with an answer of two syllables? I must be missing a
subtraction somewhere, but this seems so simple.

---

Here are the three rules for counting syllable from the linked-to website. I’m using the third one.

**1. The “Chin Method”**

Put your hand under your chin. Say the word. How many times does your chin touch your hand? This is the number of syllables.

**2. The “Clap Method”**

Clapping may help you find syllables:
Say the word. Clap each time you hear A, E, I, O, or U as a separate sound. The number of claps is the number of syllables.

**3. The “Written Method”**

- Count the number of vowels (A, E, I, O, U) in the word.
- Add 1 every time the letter ‘y’ makes the sound of a vowel (A, E, I, O, U).
- Subtract 1 for each silent vowel (like the silent ‘e’ at the end of a word).
- Subtract 1 for each diphthong or triphthong in the word.
- Does the word end with “le” or “les?” Add 1 only if the letter before the “le” is a consonant.
- The number you get is the number of syllables in your word.

Comment: Some people say "evry" which is two syllables. When I say "every" I *think* the middle syllable is barely audible, but perhaps it isn't audible at all to a listener. Few people say all three syllables cleanly and clearly.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Except when exasperated: *“Ev-er-y single time...”*

Comment: The only time every is not written as every is in dialogue: e'vry. For example. There are three syllables in the written word every. The counter you are using says:  **it may not be entirely accurate all the time but the accuracy is gradually improving**. So, there it is. You gotta read the small print.

Comment: The "written method" syllable rules doesn't actually give the number of syllables people use when they pronounce the word (and this number can vary).

Comment: @Jim as in a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8jPDdHd9y8&t=157s)

Comment: As @PeterShor points out, number of syllables does vary in real language. But in written language (using letters not sounds), there is no such thing as a "syllable" -- there is only an artificial rule about letter and hyphen placement. If you're programming it, use whatever rules you prefer -- there's no international, or even national, standard.

Comment: Thanks for the input however none of these comments really help me. I'm asking the following, "When using the written rules, how many syllables do you get for the word every". There is only one answer, take the written rules and apply them to the word every. When you do this what word do you get?

Comment: When you make an assumption, you make an S out of U and umption: Rules however I'm sure they are the same everywhere. Even should we all have the same accent, English plays fast and luce with pronunciation of the written word.  Lice-ter for Leisectersestersetershire

Comment: If you're intent on using those rather simplistic rules, ask if the middle E is silent. There are many comments above discussing that. It should be obvious that if a vowel is not pronounced, it's not the core of a syllable.

Comment: If this is a computer programming question, then it should have been posted on some Stack Exchange site dedicated to computer programming, not here. It is not practical to hope English experts will debug away your program’s bugs for you, for their expertise lies not in computer programming but in English.

Comment: Good luck with _cwm_ (fully assimilated into English, though of  course a loan-word from Welsh).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Also good luck with writing a function `f` as in `int n = f(x)` such that `f("laboratory")` returns all of 3 and 4 and 5 in a way that you can do something  meaningful with all those answers in the rest of your program. You'll  also find that `f("extraordinary")` needs to return all of 3 and 4 and 5 and 6 at the same time. Plenty more where those came from.

Comment: 'Method 3' looks like an algorithm invented to test algorithm-following prowess. For some people, it's an open invitation to come up with algorithm-busters. Yippeeeeee!

Comment: Actually, if you use the "written method" the answer is still "2 or 3" - see my answer below for why. And it still boils down to the fact that as @JohnLawler said, writing doesn't consist of syllables.

Comment: By the way, in case you are Michael Holtzscher (and, in fact, even if you're not) the CMU PD **does** in fact give you the correct number of syllables to a much greater degree of accuracy than you'll get from your own code. The reason is that every vowel is given a lexical stress marker. You can tell from the number of lexical stress markers the expected number of syllables. This, however, won't get you round the problem of variations in pronunciation and also phonological processes like compression. Writing has no syllable and lexemes have variable ones!

Comment: Just to state the obvious that is not obvious, English spelling 1) is only an approximation to pronunciation and 2) is notoriously outdated too -and- 3) different varieties do different things with spelling. So a rule based on spelling will have lots of exceptions and exceptions to those exceptions. Which is to say, it's no big deal if there's no perfect (or good) syllabification algorithm based on spelling, the best solution is a list. ow many syllables does 'irony' or 'desire' have.

Comment: "However, I’m sure the syllable rules for English are the same everywhere."  Were  you intending to make a joke there?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) with multiple levels: You care about the number of syllables produced by some quick-and-dirty rule (the “written method”) only as a reference to test your own quick-and-dirty heuristic. How is this not “garbage in – garbage out”? Why not at least use a quality reference, e.g. IPA from Wiktionary (which also is probably quicker than all the effort you put in here)? […]

Comment: […] While I can imagine at least some applications for a syllable-counting program, I fail to see any where reproducing a specific suboptimal rule is the actual goal. I recommend thinking from whatever your application is, as this will probably clearly point to what syllable number makes most sense for you.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/594992/2085).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## No fixed answers

Your problem with *every* is that many but hardly all words whose pronunciations end in [ɹi] or [ɹiz] have a variable number of syllables depending on how reduced the vowel sound immediately before their rhotic is, and sometimes by how reduced the vowel sound immediately after it is, too.

*Every* is just one of these. That’s why *everybody* can have both four and five syllables. It’s not a fixed number.

But even these words are not the only ones with this property. Any “written rule” that pretends to tell you how many syllables there are
in *actuary,
adultery,
alimentary,
auxiliary,
bakery,
baptistery,
battery,
cemetery, coupe, extraordinary, fiery, film, laboratory, library,
medicine, military, necessary, oratory, ornery, raspberry, secretary, Salisbury, territory*
needs to be consigned to the rubbish bin. It’s just spouting meaningless nonsense.

That’s because each of those words can be — **and is** — pronounced with a number of syllables that varies by region, speaker, and utterance.  Many, many more such words exist. They have no single integer answer to their syllable count. It just is not possible.

Then there’s the inconvenient truth that countless word pairs like *powers* and *hours*, or *higher* and *fire*, are perfect rhymes for some people but not for others. Even the same speaker can **choose** how many syllables to use for the sake of poetic meter. A given word can have a variable syllable count from one line of verse to the next, even by the very same poet, when the meter demands this.

#### There is no such thing as a “written” syllable: syllables are part of pronunciation, not of writing.

It is therefore fundamentally impossible to count syllables merely by looking at the letters with which a word is written. You have to know what people actually say, and exactly what people say has no single fixed answer which is invariant across time and space. Writing is immaterial and irrelevant to actual speech.

Comment: Perhaps the closest thing to written syllable rules are the algorithms used for automated hyphenation. I think one of the original TeX papers described its method.

Comment: Then one gets into issues as to whether "jewelry" and "jewellery" are the same word. The first is generally pronounced as two syllables, while the second spelling suggests a three syllable pronunciation. If the US and UK both spell and pronounce the word differently, are they the "same" word, or are they two "different" words that have a very close origin? Should an American spell the word "jewelry" even if they pronounce it with three syllables? What about a Briton pronouncing it with two?

Comment: @Acccumulation: in that particular example, I'd argue that they are just the US and UK spellings - i.e. the same word, with two valid spellings depending on where you are - and separate from how they're pronounced, which depends on your accent (among other factors).

Comment: @Barmar Hyphenation rules are often talked about like that but they don't work according to syllabic principles.

Comment: @Acccumulation That's an interesting example... by the OP's spelling-based heuristic, "jewelry" should have three syllables, while "jewellery" should have *four*. As an American who uses the spelling "jewelry," I think of the word as having three syllables, although the way I pronounce it in casual speech is probably closer to two.

Comment: @tchrist thank you for the precise answer that was exactly what I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 19):

### Short answer:

Because of a phonological process know as compression, *every* can be said with either 2 or 3 syllables. This happens to coincide with the "written method" described (see full post below) which comes up with exactly that answer. There's no way round the two answer problem. Writing, of course, doesn't consist of sound and therefore doesn't have syllables, and this is part of the issue.

---

### Full answer:

Well, all of these rules are problematic. To give an example, the chin one won't work at all if a consonant at the beginning of a syllable requires the mouth to be more open than the following vowel. This is what happens in the second syllable of the word *sorry.* Your chin's only going to hit your hand for the first syllable there, not the second (try it!). However, setting those many various issues aside, let's have a look at the interesting problem that the Original Poster is having with the word *every.*

**Special features of *Every***:

There's a reason why the Original Poster is having a problem with *every*, in particular. As mentioned in the comments by @Peter Shor and @John Lawler, pronunciation varies between individuals, and also within the speech of any given single individual. So a given person might say the word *every* with either two or three syllables depending on many different factors, for example the number of unstressed syllables following the word, how fast they're speaking, who they're speaking to and why they're speaking in the first place. The reason this is possible is that the word *every* is liable to a phonetic and phonological process known as  ᴄᴏᴍᴘʀᴇssɪᴏɴ.

English syllables come  in two parts. There's the Onset and the Rhyme. The rhyme is obligatory, but the onset is an optional feature. The onset is usually a consonant or group of consonants at the beginning of the syllable, before the vowel. The rhyme is everything else. So in the word *cat* /kæt/, the onset is /k/ and the rhyme is /æt/.

Now the rhyme is further split into two parts. It has the most sonorous musical and vowellish part, the Nucleus, which is obligatory. It can also have a Coda, which involves the syllable getting both quieter and less sonorant. Codas are usually consonants or consonant clusters. So in /kæt/ the nucleus is /æ/ and the coda is /t/. The syllable itself represents a peak in sonority. If it has an onset and a coda, then these will represent the dips in sonority at either end of the syllable.

Notice that I said that nucleuses are *usually* vowels. This is because we can, in special circumstances, have a syllabic consonant. This is when the nucleus of a syllable is a consonant. For example, in the word *criticism* /krɪtɪsɪzm/, the last syllable just consists of an /m/ sound. The consonants  /r, l/ and the nasals /m, n, ŋ/ also frequently occur as syllabic consonants in English.

Back to *every.* The most expanded pronunciation of the word *every* is this:

1. /'evəri/

I've used the standard UK transcription here, as used by John Wells in the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary. You will see that the second vowel there is a schwa /ə/, a mid-central vowel which only ever occurs in unstressed syllables.

If we agree with Wells that, other things being equal, a consonant will usually be syllabified with a stressed syllable when between two vowels, then the /v/ in *every* belongs in the first, stressed syllable. In the pronunciation of *every* shown above, the second syllable has no onset and consists of just a rhyme with a schwa as its nucleus.

In English when a schwa is followed by an /l/ or /r/ or a nasal such as /m, n, ŋ/ there is usually an alternative possible pronunciation, which has no schwa, but instead uses the following consonant as a nucleus, in other words as a syllabic consonant. When transcribing the word, this can be shown by using a small diacritic under the consonant in question. With the word *every* this would look like this:

2. /'evr̩i/

This pronunciation of *every*, like the one shown in (1) has three syllables, but this time the nucleus of the second syllable is the consonant /r/. This consonant will have a longer duration here than it would if occurring in an onset or a coda.

For most speakers, however, it is possible for a further reduction to take place and for the /r/ there to become the onset of the following syllable. In this case the /r/ will be quieter and significantly shorter in duration. This 'process' results in the loss of a syllable, of course. The resulting pronunciation is shown below:

3. /evri/

In the second and last syllable here the /r/ is the onset and /i/ the nucleus.

This same type of variation can be seen  in (4, 5) below:

4. happening: hæpənɪŋ --> hæpn̩ɪŋ -->  hæpnɪŋ
5. pedalling: pedəlɪŋ --> pədl̩ɪŋ --> pedlɪŋ

This is one type of compression. [There are others.](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/p201-9-lecture.pdf)

---

**The Original Poster's Question**

The Original Poster asks how many syllables *every* has according to the "Written Method." The answer here is easy: 2 or 3. If the person applying the rule arbitrarily decides that the pronunciation is **/'evəri/**, then they will decide that the second < e > in *every* has a sound and is not a silent letter. In this case *every* has three syllables according to the given rules. However, if they decide the pronunciation is **/'evri/**, then the second < e > in *every* is silent and they will therefore need to subtract 1 to find the number of syllables, giving them the answer 2. The reality is that writing doesn't have syllables (apart from those assigned in the mind of the reader).

I can hear some people saying "OK, but which pronunciation is the ***right*** one, the one with two syllables or the one with three?" [Sigh. Whatever happened to free speech?!]

There *is* no correct pronunciation. The rules of English phonology allow for both. Native speakers use both. That's all there is to it.  If you're looking to beat yourself with a riding crop for using the wrong one, go ahead, feel free. Make your choice and stick with it and administer your punishment accordingly. If you feel a deep need to apply your riding crop to others, however, please do ask first.

Comment: Right on. ([Though I spell it _rime_,](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/rimecoherence.pdf) because Bolinger)

Comment: Papering over the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger) by using /ə/ everywhere is good and makes things easier to explain—although personally I’m [losing faith with the oft-repeated mantra that schwa can “never” be stressed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt66Je3o0Qg). Just one thing: I know ***you*** understand it, but many North American and international readers will be even more confused by the practice of writing phonemic /e/ for phonetic [ɛ] than they will by that of writing phonemic /r/ for phonetic [ɹ].

Comment: @tchrist Yes, but you lot know that us lot are eccentric, though. I think they'll understand.

Comment: @JohnLawler: You might want to revise this sentence in your paper, in light of well, late enlightenment: "The residue of 4 words that belong to neither of these classes comprises *pump*, *trump*, *compass*, and *crumpet*." You might reconsider one of those as a candidate for the *pejorative* category, in both groups: "unpleasant people" and "unpleasant sounds".  ;-)

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the paper. I wasn't aware of that one. In British English your humanoid –əŋk rimes would include *funk, hunk* and *drunk*. I assume *stunk* and *sunk* are out of the pejoratives for being inflections? It does make one wonder, however, if sound symbolism has affected the development of the synchronic inflections. (Don't know why that rime got me thinking most - shrugs)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore Phonosemantics is like that. Just repeating a list of simplex words with the same assonance or rime tends to make the semantic neutrinos swarm. When I give talks about this stuff, I usually start off just by reciting some lists and watch the audience catch on. It's interesting stuff.